# React Native Metro Bundler Crashing

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules, metro-bundler

So I'm getting this error every time I run any react native application on my system.
The metro builder crashes almost instantaneously as soon as I start the application.
This happens with expo and react native cli apps both.
While in this screenshot I'm using a monorepo, I have encountered this error in other react native applications too.

[image: screenshot of the error]

I have tried opening vscode in admin mode but the error is still there.
Have also tried changing the prefix using the
`npm edit config`

Would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: you need to fire reset cache command

Comment: I  have tried that but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try This :->

```
(1) npm cache clean --force

(2) rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

(3) npm install

(4) npm start
```

Comment: I have tried that, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR; Have Metro ignore changes in the respective directory

1. If it doesn't exist, create a file named `metro.config.js` in your project's root directory.
2. The file should include the following lines:

```js
// 'exclusionList' used to be called 'blacklist' before React Native 0.64
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');
// ...
module.exports = {
// ...
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: exclusionList([
      new RegExp("^E:\/<your_path_name>\\/.git\\/.*$"),
      // ...
    ]),
    // ...
  }
}
```

#### What's going on

To implement hot reloading, Metro is constantly watching for file changes in the project directory. In your case, Metro tried to read the information on a file without having the necessary permissions. `.git/fsmonitor--deamon` ironically watches for file changes, too, and creates cookie files in the process. These cookies are only for use by git itself, therefore the restrictive access policy.

Comment: This is does not solve it either.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the Regex? My guess is that it doesn't capture `.git` quite yet. Does it work for you if you filter for ` /.git\/.*/` instead of `new RegExp("^E:\/<your_path_name>\\/.git\\/.*$")`?